emit different logs in different format based on condition like security events, normal software operation events etc to the std out
I am stuck at situation where i have to
emit logs in different format based on condition like security events, normal software operation events etc to the std out.
example
lets say

security events like authentication failure/success should start
like SEC EVENT,LEVEL,  DATETIME, MESSAGE
normal events should start
like LEVEL, DATETIME, MESSAGE

I tried using formatter and Filters but all these make decision at the time when my custom logger class is initialized, I need to make that decision during execution time
example:
log = CustomLogClass()

log.info("msg") # this should emit in some format
log.sec_info() # this should emit in other format


In your CustomLogClass you can declare two python loggers, each one with a different format, and use the right logger in the right situation.

@Fado request to explain with help of some code

what is suggested in the comments will be something similar to this:
class CustomLogClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.normal_logger = self._create_logger('normal_logger', 
                                                 '%(levelname)s, %(asctime)s, %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.sec_logger = self._create_logger('sec_logger'),
                                              '%(levelname)s, %(asctime)s, %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    def _create_logger(self, name, log_format, level=logging.INFO):
        # Create a new logger with the specified name
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger

    def info(self, message):
        """Logs a normal event."""
        self.normal_logger.info(message)

    def sec_info(self, message):
        """Logs a security event."""
        self.sec_logger.info(message)


This is what I meant in my comment:
 import logging


class CustomLogClass:
    logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
    logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter1 = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler1.setFormatter(formatter1)
    logger1.addHandler(console_handler1)

    # Configure the second logger with a different format
    logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')
    logger2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter2 = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler2 = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler2.setFormatter(formatter2)
    logger2.addHandler(console_handler2)

    def log_situation1(self, message):
        self.logger1.info(message)

    def log_situation2(self, message):
        self.logger2.info(message)


custom_logger = CustomLogClass()
is_situation1 = True
if is_situation1:
    custom_logger.log_situation1("situation 1 happened")
else:
    custom_logger.log_situation2("situation 2 happened")

